# Submitting a specific row of a form which is generated by a loop

Tags: php, html

This is the code for the admin panel of a certain site. Appointments asked by customers will be shown in this page. The admin will be able to `change` the appointments based on availability.

```
<?php 

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

?>

<form action="adminEdit.php" method="POST">
 <tr>   

  <td><input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $row['Name'];?>"></input></td> 
  <td><input type="text" id="address" value="<?php echo $row['Address'];?>"></input></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="phone" value="<?php echo $row['Phone'];?>"></input></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="license" value="<?php echo $row['Car_License_No'];?>"></input></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="engine" value="<?php echo $row['Car_Engine_No'];?>"></input></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="date" value="<?php echo $row['Date'];?>"></input></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="mechanic" value="<?php echo $row['Mechanic'];?>"></input></td>

  <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Change"/></td>

 </tr>
</form>

<?php  

 }

?>
```

Here, each row of data has a corresponding button which will be used for changing or modifying the records of that particular row. Once the admin changes a specific appointment it should get updated in database.

My problem is, all the rows are getting generated by a while loop. Now how can I access a specific row when the `change` button of that specific row has been clicked ? As the rows are getting generated by a loop, I won`t be able to access them by`name`or`id`because all of them will have the same`name`and`id`.

Searched for relevant questions but none of them matched with my scenario. It will be of great help getting an answer. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I'd be inclined to take the output from being in the loop for better control over the data and resolving the issue. You're also creating a new form on each loop.
Just loop the DB and create a new variable, then use that variable to output the data in the form.

Example code to show the basic idea, not tested or stating it's complete etc:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $someNewVar[$row['id']] = $row; 
  // The 'id' index would be from DB which identifies individual rows
}
?>

<form action="adminEdit.php" method="POST">

<?php
foreach ($someNewVar as $index => $value) {
?>
<tr>       
  <td>
    <input 
        type="text" 
        id="<?php echo $index;?>" 
        value="<?php echo $value['Name'];?>">
    </input>
  </td> 
   <td>
     <input 
       type="submit" 
       name="submit" 
       value="Change"/>
   </td>
</tr>

<?php  
 }
?>
</form>
```

Then you'd need to have the row ID passed from clicking the submit button.

---

On a side note, this whole approach could be tidied up, and data should be obtained in one file separate to where you output it.
Then in the file which obtains the data you can set the array to something which is also identified in the output file to manage if no data was obtained.
ie
**getData.php**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dataFromDb[$row['id']] = $row; 
}
$someNewVar = !empty($dataFromDb) ? $dataFromDb : false;
```

showData.php

```
if ($someNewVar) { 
  // do the loop and form
} else { 
  echo 'sorry no data found';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your precise answer. Just for asking, can there be a way if I put a hidden value in each input ?

Comment: You can put hidden values in each loop of the form (each row) such as the ID and send that on submit.